# matching tab with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am new to sed, so want to know how can I match tab. I have some text like this -

```
    line one {
            line two {
                    filler {
                            text value
                    }
                    line four
            }
    }
```

I am using the expression, which matches the above text if there are no tabs.

```
sed -i -e "/ line two {/,/}/s/text .*\$/text new/" $file
```

However, there are 2 tabs before "line two" and 3 tabs before "filler" and 4 tabs before "text value".

Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In GNU `sed`, tabs are represented as `\t`.  So, the substitution will be successfully made with the following:

```
sed -i -e "/\tline two {/,/}/s/text .*\$/text new/" "$file"
```

The only required change was to replace `/ line two {/` with `/\tline two {/`.  The command `/s/text .*\$/text new/` does not require any change because it does not attempt to match the white space that precedes `text`.  If there might be a tab that *follows* `text`, then use:

```
sed -i -e "/\tline two {/,/}/s/text[[:space:]].*\$/text new/" "$file"
```

If you are unsure of what white space character will appear, the expression `[[:space:]]` can be used to match any kind of white space.